# Where should I ask a question about artificial intelligence?

Tags: discussion, questions

I was interested in knowing which stack exchange site is appropriate for artificial Intelligence questions.

Specifically, I wanted to understand the following statement better:

> statistical learning is not the path to AI (Artificial Intelligence)

I love machine and statistical learning and would be very interested in knowing why people feel that way or whether that's even the goal of statistical learning! Maybe statistical learning is not even interested on being AI and something else.

Anyhow, I was interested in either, references about that or maybe posting this question on one of the stack exchange sites, but was unsure if it was appropriate or not.

I also know there is a CS stack exchange site, programmers and data science, or even maths. Which one is the best to ask a variant of this question?

Comment: This could be a tough one. See [the blog post about the demise of the AI.SE beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/no-artificial-intelligence-in-area-51/). Given the mention of statistical learning though, my inclination is to say give it a shot here if the statistical aspect isn't trivial or incidental, but actually an important part of the question. Just make it clear that you're not asking for opinions or a very broad range of possible answers, as those would be tempting reasons to put the question on hold as currently presented.

Comment: From a purely definitional point of view, [CogSci.SE](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) ought to be the port of call for AI questions, as I don't think anyone could argue that artificial intelligence isn't an aspect of cognitive science. I don't think CogSci.SE, as it currently stands, could provide the answers you're looking for though.

Answer (score 12):

I'd be inclined to say that a question on AI including a comparison with *statistical learning* would be pretty clearly [on topic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here (and I might have considered it at least potentially on topic even without that).

It appears to be perhaps most directly [on topic](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com) -- both AI and machine learning are on topic there.

If the question leans toward the theoretical, you might also consider [Theoretical Computer Science](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com)

However, wherever you post it, you would nevertheless need to avoid heading much toward either a chatty/opinion-based or an overly broad question, because either would still be in danger of [closure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: +1, I think it would be sufficiently on-topic here, but he'd probably get better answers on CS or TCS.

Answer (score 2):

Kinda on the same vein with Glen_b, I'd probably say it depends on what aspect of AI you refer to. If it's a practical programming aspect then probably SO or Programmers would be the place to go. If it's an learning aspect, probably here or CS.

Answer (score 1):

Q&A site for AI entered private beta, so you can now ask non-statistical AI questions there:

- [http://ai.stackexchange.com/](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93481/artificial-intelligence/visit)

Comment: Related discussion: http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4243